# Maven suddenly downloading maven-clover2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, clover

Yesterday, while compiling our web application using Maven, it started downloading the maven-clover2-plugin version 3.1.3-SNAPSHOT

```
com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

Without success because this version is not yet added to the repository ([link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.maven.plugins/maven-clover2-plugin))

I ran Maven in debug mode in order to get the dependency tree, but I couldn't find why it is downloaded. Here's a snapshot of Maven logs:

```
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.6
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.6
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.6
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG] maven-clover2-plugin: resolved to version 3.1.3-SNAPSHOT from local repository
```

Do you know which library or plugin is dependent maven-clover2-plugin:3.1.3? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just do `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where it came from

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't show the clover2 plugin. It seems as it's not part of my project dependencies by it is used by Maven itself. For now, I was able to get working so I consider it as a low-priority problem. Thank you for you time